# How can I specify to use a generic overloaded function in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

For instance, we have the following code

```
func testFunc<T>(_ value: T) {
    // do something
}

// This overloaded function is provided on a newer version of SDK, we need to check the SDK version.
func testFunc<T>(_ value: T?) {
    // do something if we have an optional value
}
```

If I have an **optional** value, how can I specify that I want to call the **first** function instead of the **second** function? The rationale behind this is that the **second** function may only be available on a newer SDK, so I need to have fallback.

Comment: Are you sure if it's the old version of the SDK, old version of the function will be called? If the functions are in UIKit, we can see both in the newest Xcode, but call `testFunc` with an optional value will automatically resolve to the second function. And Xcode will give error if we add availability annotation to the second function.

Answer (score 0):

Swift tries to pick the most specific function possible.
So to call `testFunc<T>(_ value: T)` you have to pass there a non-optional `T`. If you pass there an optional or force-unwrapped `T` second function `testFunc<T>(_ value: T?)` will be called.

You can not explicitly tell compiler which overloaded function to use, you can only modify parameters so they exactly match overloaded function you want to call.

This snippet guarantees, that `testFunc<T>(_ value: T)` will be called

```
let optional: Int? = 5
if let optional = optional {
   testFunc(optional)
}
```

Comment: I know. In this situation I want to explicitly reference the first function `testFunc<T>(_ value: T)` with an optional value, that's the problem I want to solve.

Comment: You can not explicitly tell compiler which overloaded function to use. You can only manipulate parameters so the correct overloaded function will get called.

Comment: I'm not sure with that. Maybe there is a solution?

Answer (score -1):

```
if let value = value {
    testFunc(value)
}
```

Comment: I want to call `testFunc<T>(_ value: T)` with an optional value. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes I writed that in my snippet func testFunc<T>(_ value: T?)

Comment: I may have not make my point clear. When the both functions exist, I want to explicitly call `testFunc<T>(_ value: T)` with an optional value.

Comment: if let value = value {

Comment: This seems doesn't work. What should we put in the else clause? We still need to check if the second function is available, if it's not we need to call the first function explicitly.